# How to move variables from subquery to an outer query - postgres?

Tags: postgresql, variables, subquery

I am writing query below and as you can see it has a lot of subqueries. I would like to throw out from subquery to outer query "dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve" and "dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica", so that I don't need to change them every time. I have tried many solutions which I have found here but nothing seems to work. Any guess?

```
select distinct on (upniki.naziv)
upniki.naziv, 
b.stevilo,  
b.glavnica_skupaj/b.stevilo as povprecna_glavnica, 
b.glavnica_skupaj,
coalesce(taksa_vlozitve,0)+coalesce(dodatna_taksa,0) as celotna_sodna_taksa,
coalesce(stroski,0)-coalesce(taksa_vlozitve,0)+ coalesce(dodatni_odvetniski,0)as vsi_odvetniski_stroski,
coalesce(stroski_izvrsitelja,0) as stroski_izvrsitelja,
coalesce(pravdni,0) as pravdni,
coalesce(glavnicapok,0)+coalesce(glavnicapokobresti,0) as pokrivanje_glavice_z_obrestmi,
coalesce(poksodnataksavlozitve,0)+coalesce(poksodnataksavlozitveobresti,0)+coalesce(pokdodatnasodnataksa,0)+coalesce(pokdodatnasodnataksaobresti,0) as pokrivanje_takse_z_obrestmi,
coalesce(pokodvstroskivlozitve,0)+coalesce(pokodvstroskivlozitveobresti,0)+coalesce(pokdodatniodvstroski,0)+coalesce(pokdodatniodvstroskiobresti,0) as pokrivanje_odvetniskih_z_obrestmi,
coalesce(pokstroskiizvrsitelja,0)+coalesce(pokstroskiizvrsiteljaobresti,0) as pokrivanje_stroskov_izvrsitelja_z_obrestmi,
coalesce(pokpravdnistroski,0)+coalesce(pokpravdnistroskiobresti,0) as pokrivanje_pravdnih_z_obrestmi,
((coalesce(glavnicapok,0)+coalesce(glavnicapokobresti,0))/b.glavnica_skupaj) as uspesnosti_glavnice,
((coalesce(poksodnataksavlozitve,0)+coalesce(poksodnataksavlozitveobresti,0)+coalesce(pokdodatnasodnataksa,0)+coalesce(pokdodatnasodnataksaobresti,0))/(coalesce(taksa_vlozitve,0)+coalesce(dodatna_taksa,1))) as uspesnosti_taks,
((coalesce(pokodvstroskivlozitve,0)+coalesce(pokodvstroskivlozitveobresti,0)+coalesce(pokdodatniodvstroski,0)+coalesce(pokdodatniodvstroskiobresti,0))/(coalesce(stroski,0)-coalesce(taksa_vlozitve,0)+coalesce(dodatni_odvetniski,1))) as uspesnosti_odvetniskih_stroskov,
((coalesce(pokstroskiizvrsitelja,0)+coalesce(pokstroskiizvrsiteljaobresti,0))/coalesce(stroski_izvrsitelja,1)) as uspesnosti_stroskov_izvrsitelja,
((coalesce(pokpravdnistroski,0)+coalesce(pokpravdnistroskiobresti,0))/coalesce(pravdni,1)) as uspesnosti_pravdni,
coalesce(a.pokrivanje,0) as pokrivanje_glavnice_z_vsemi_placili,
(coalesce(a.pokrivanje,0)/b.glavnica_skupaj) as procent,
coalesce(taksa_vlozitve,0) as taksa_vlozitve,
coalesce(stroski,0)-coalesce(taksa_vlozitve) as odv_stroski_vlozitve,
coalesce(dodatna_taksa,0) as dodatna_taksa,
coalesce(dodatni_odvetniski,0) as dodatni_odvetniski,
coalesce(stroski_izvrsitelja,0)as stroski_izvrsitelja,
coalesce(pravdni,0) as pravdni_stroski,
coalesce(glavnicapok,0) as glavnicapok,
coalesce(glavnicapokobresti,0) as glavnicapokobresti,
coalesce (poksodnataksavlozitve,0) as poksodnataksavlozitve,
coalesce(poksodnataksavlozitveobresti) as poksodnataksavlozitveobresti,
coalesce (pokodvstroskivlozitve,0) as pokodvstroskivlozitve,
coalesce(pokodvstroskivlozitveobresti,0) as pokoodvstroskivlozitveobresti,
coalesce(pokdodatnasodnataksa,0) as pokdodatnasodnataksa,
coalesce(pokdodatnasodnataksaobresti,0) as pokdodatnasodnataksaobresti,
coalesce(pokdodatniodvstroski,0) as pokdodatniodvstroski,
coalesce(pokdodatniodvstroskiobresti,0) as pokdodatniodvstroskiobresti,
coalesce(pokstroskiizvrsitelja,0) as pokstroskiizvrsitelja,
coalesce(pokstroskiizvrsiteljaobresti,0) as pokstroskiizvrsiteljaobresti,
coalesce(pokpravdnistroski,0) as pokpravdnistroski,
coalesce(pokpravdnistroskiobresti,0) as pokpravdnistroskiobresti
from dolzniki_terjatve
inner join paketi on dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket=paketi.id_paket
inner join upniki on paketi.id_upnik=upniki.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, coalesce(sum(znesek),0)-coalesce(sum(preplacilo),0) as pokrivanje
           from specifikacije1, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi
           where specifikacije1.referenca=dolzniki_terjatve.referenca and dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket=paketi.id_paket
           and datumplacila <=date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01' 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           group by paketi.id_upnik) as a on paketi.id_upnik=a.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, count(referenca) as stevilo, sum(glavnica) as glavnica_skupaj, coalesce(sum(stroski_vlozitve),0) as stroski, coalesce(sum(sodna_taksa_vlozitve),1) as taksa_vlozitve 
           from dolzniki_terjatve, paketi
           where dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket=paketi.id_paket 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01' 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500  
           group by paketi.id_upnik) 
           as b on paketi.id_upnik=b.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(znesek) as dodatna_taksa 
           from dolzniki_dodatni_stroski, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi 
           where dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=dolzniki_dodatni_stroski.referenca and dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket=paketi.id_paket 
           and tip_stroskov='1' 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'         
           and datum <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tabledodatnataksa on paketi.id_upnik=tabledodatnataksa.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(znesek) as dodatni_odvetniski 
           from dolzniki_dodatni_stroski, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi 
           where dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=dolzniki_dodatni_stroski.referenca and dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket=paketi.id_paket
           and tip_stroskov='2' 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01' and 
           datum <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tabledodatniodv on paketi.id_upnik=tabledodatniodv.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, coalesce(sum(znesek),0) as stroski_izvrsitelja 
           from dolzniki_dodatni_stroski, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi 
           where dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=dolzniki_dodatni_stroski.referenca and dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket=paketi.id_paket
           and tip_stroskov='3'
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01' 
           and datum <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tablestroskiizv on paketi.id_upnik=tablestroskiizv.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(znesek) as pravdni 
           from dolzniki_dodatni_stroski, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi 
           where dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=dolzniki_dodatni_stroski.referenca and dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket=paketi.id_paket
           and tip_stroskov='4'
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-06-01'
           and datum <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month'
           group by paketi.id_upnik) as tablepravdni on paketi.id_upnik=tablepravdni.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(specifikacije_postavke.placilo) as glavnicapok 
           from specifikacije_postavke, specifikacije1, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi
           where specifikacije1.idizracun=specifikacije_postavke.idizracun and dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=specifikacije1.referenca and paketi.id_paket=dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket
           and postavka='1' and obresti=false
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'
           and datumplacila <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tabelaglavnice on paketi.id_upnik=tabelaglavnice.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(specifikacije_postavke.placilo) as glavnicapokobresti 
           from specifikacije_postavke, specifikacije1, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi
           where specifikacije1.idizracun=specifikacije_postavke.idizracun and dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=specifikacije1.referenca and paketi.id_paket=dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket
           and postavka='1' and obresti=true
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'
           and datumplacila <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tabelaglavniceobresti on paketi.id_upnik=tabelaglavniceobresti.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(specifikacije_postavke.placilo) as pokodvstroskivlozitve 
           from specifikacije_postavke, specifikacije1, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi
           where specifikacije1.idizracun=specifikacije_postavke.idizracun and dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=specifikacije1.referenca and paketi.id_paket=dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket
           and postavka='2' and obresti=false
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'
           and datumplacila <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tabelaodvstroski on paketi.id_upnik=tabelaodvstroski.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(specifikacije_postavke.placilo) as pokodvstroskivlozitveobresti 
           from specifikacije_postavke, specifikacije1, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi
           where specifikacije1.idizracun=specifikacije_postavke.idizracun and dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=specifikacije1.referenca and paketi.id_paket=dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket
           and postavka='2' and obresti=true
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'
           and datumplacila <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tabelaodvstroskiobresti on paketi.id_upnik=tabelaodvstroskiobresti.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(specifikacije_postavke.placilo) as poksodnataksavlozitve 
           from specifikacije_postavke, specifikacije1, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi
           where specifikacije1.idizracun=specifikacije_postavke.idizracun and dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=specifikacije1.referenca and paketi.id_paket=dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket
           and postavka='3' and obresti=false
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'
           and datumplacila <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tabelasodnataksavlozitve on paketi.id_upnik=tabelasodnataksavlozitve.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(specifikacije_postavke.placilo) as poksodnataksavlozitveobresti 
           from specifikacije_postavke, specifikacije1, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi
           where specifikacije1.idizracun=specifikacije_postavke.idizracun and dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=specifikacije1.referenca and paketi.id_paket=dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket
           and postavka='3' and obresti=true
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'
           and datumplacila <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tabelasodnataksavlozitveobresti on paketi.id_upnik=tabelasodnataksavlozitveobresti.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(specifikacije_postavke.placilo) as pokdodatnasodnataksa
           from specifikacije_postavke, specifikacije1, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi
           where specifikacije1.idizracun=specifikacije_postavke.idizracun and dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=specifikacije1.referenca and paketi.id_paket=dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket
           and postavkastroski='1' and obresti=false
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'
           and datumplacila <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tabeladodatnasodnataksa on paketi.id_upnik=tabeladodatnasodnataksa.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(specifikacije_postavke.placilo) as pokdodatnasodnataksaobresti
           from specifikacije_postavke, specifikacije1, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi
           where specifikacije1.idizracun=specifikacije_postavke.idizracun and dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=specifikacije1.referenca and paketi.id_paket=dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket
           and postavkastroski='1' and obresti=true
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'
           and datumplacila <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tabeladodatnasodnataksaobresti on paketi.id_upnik=tabeladodatnasodnataksaobresti.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(specifikacije_postavke.placilo) as pokdodatniodvstroski
           from specifikacije_postavke, specifikacije1, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi
           where specifikacije1.idizracun=specifikacije_postavke.idizracun and dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=specifikacije1.referenca and paketi.id_paket=dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket
           and postavkastroski='2' and obresti=false
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'
           and datumplacila <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tabeladodatniodvstroski on paketi.id_upnik=tabeladodatniodvstroski.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(specifikacije_postavke.placilo) as pokdodatniodvstroskiobresti
           from specifikacije_postavke, specifikacije1, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi
           where specifikacije1.idizracun=specifikacije_postavke.idizracun and dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=specifikacije1.referenca and paketi.id_paket=dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket
           and postavkastroski='2' and obresti=true
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'
           and datumplacila <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tabeladodatniodvstroskiobresti on paketi.id_upnik=tabeladodatniodvstroskiobresti.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(specifikacije_postavke.placilo) as pokstroskiizvrsitelja
           from specifikacije_postavke, specifikacije1, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi
           where specifikacije1.idizracun=specifikacije_postavke.idizracun and dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=specifikacije1.referenca and paketi.id_paket=dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket
           and postavkastroski='3' and obresti=false
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'
           and datumplacila <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tabelastroskiizvrsitelja on paketi.id_upnik=tabelastroskiizvrsitelja.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(specifikacije_postavke.placilo) as pokstroskiizvrsiteljaobresti
           from specifikacije_postavke, specifikacije1, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi
           where specifikacije1.idizracun=specifikacije_postavke.idizracun and dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=specifikacije1.referenca and paketi.id_paket=dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket
           and postavkastroski='3' and obresti=true
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'
           and datumplacila <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tabelastroskiizvrsiteljaobresti on paketi.id_upnik=tabelastroskiizvrsiteljaobresti.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(specifikacije_postavke.placilo) as pokpravdnistroski
           from specifikacije_postavke, specifikacije1, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi
           where specifikacije1.idizracun=specifikacije_postavke.idizracun and dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=specifikacije1.referenca and paketi.id_paket=dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket
           and postavkastroski='4' and obresti=false
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'
           and datumplacila <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tabelapravdnistroski on paketi.id_upnik=tabelapravdnistroski.id_upnik
left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(specifikacije_postavke.placilo) as pokpravdnistroskiobresti
           from specifikacije_postavke, specifikacije1, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi
           where specifikacije1.idizracun=specifikacije_postavke.idizracun and dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=specifikacije1.referenca and paketi.id_paket=dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket
           and postavkastroski='4' and obresti=true
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'
           and datumplacila <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik)
           as tabelapravdnistroskiobresti on paketi.id_upnik=tabelapravdnistroskiobresti.id_upnik
where upniki.id_upnik in (131,141,1009, 1000)
```

Comment: Maybe make a CTE that just selects those two values, and join with that CTE in your query?

Comment: What is quite interesting you have where condition `id_upnik in (131,141,1009, 1000)` in main query, but your subqueries in join's  don't have this conditions repeated. Is this efficient enough ?

Comment: Please simplify the query to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Kadet it does work perfectly, I have checked with another, longer query. Because subquery is connected to paketi.id_upnik...

Comment: @TheImpaler what do you mean with simplifying? Just look at the first left join. I would like to substite fix date ('2018-06-01 and 2019-01-01) and principal range '0' and '500' with something dynamic, so that I don't need to change fix dates and principal ranges XXX times. Because this query also has 35 unions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can define params in WITH section and use them in subqueries

**Simple example**

```
with 
  params as (select 1 param_from, 1 param_to)
select header_id, count(*) from position, params
where position.header_id between param_from and param_to
group by header_id
```

[DB Fiddle to play with](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=9c7160acd7407befcb33bd212beae27c)

Query after refactor

```
with 
  params as (select '2018-06-01'::timestamp p_datum_vlozitve_from, '2019-01-01'::timestamp  p_datum_vlozitve_to)
select distinct on (upniki.naziv)
upniki.naziv, 
b.stevilo, 
.......  original query  .....
```

And instead of constans, values from param query can be used.

For example in `tabledodatnataksa` subquery

```
select paketi.id_upnik, sum(znesek) as dodatna_taksa 
           from dolzniki_dodatni_stroski, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi 
           where dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=dolzniki_dodatni_stroski.referenca and dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket=paketi.id_paket 
           and tip_stroskov='1' 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'         
           and datum <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik
```

add `param` to tables and use `p_datum_vlozitve_from` instead of `2018-06-01` and `p_datum_vlozitve_to` instead of `2019-01-01`

```
select paketi.id_upnik, sum(znesek) as dodatna_taksa 
           from dolzniki_dodatni_stroski, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi, param 
           where dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=dolzniki_dodatni_stroski.referenca and dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket=paketi.id_paket 
           and tip_stroskov='1' 
           and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500
           and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >=p_datum_vlozitve_from and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < p_datum_vlozitve_to         
           and datum <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
           group by paketi.id_upnik
```

Just small note

In JOIN subqueries there is a lot of repetitive code.. for example
`tabledodatnataksa,tabledodatniodv,tablestroskiizv,tablepravdni`
can be easily refactor to one subquery

```
select paketi.id_upnik, 
       sum(znesek) filter(where tip_stroskov='1') as dodatna_taksa, 
       sum(znesek) filter(where tip_stroskov='2') as dodatni_odvetniski, 
       coalesce(sum(znesek) filter(where tip_stroskov='3'),0) as stroski_izvrsitelja, 
       sum(znesek) filter(where tip_stroskov='4') as pravdni 
from dolzniki_dodatni_stroski, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi 
    where dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=dolzniki_dodatni_stroski.referenca and dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket=paketi.id_paket 
          and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > 0 and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < 500
          and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >='2018-06-01' and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < '2019-01-01'         
          and datum <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '7 month' 
          group by paketi.id_upnik
```

Comment: unfortunatelly I have never used in with section till now so I don't know what to do with this information :-)

Comment: So if you want to refactor query, start using it. I've added an example how to do replacement for one subquery.

Comment: It says p_datum_vlozitve_from doesnt exists. If i put it to '' , it says ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "p_datum_vlozitve_from"

Comment: I've added timestamp cast to with section  `with 
  params as (select '2018-06-01'::timestamp p_datum_vlozitve_from, '2019-01-01'::timestamp  p_datum_vlozitve_to)`

Comment: also you should add param to table list. Instead of `from dolzniki_dodatni_stroski, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi ` there must be `from dolzniki_dodatni_stroski, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi, param `

Comment: Can you pls help me with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72804923/how-to-set-more-than-one-value-in-param-postgres