# How to set more than one value in param - postgres

Tags: postgresql, parameters

I am having this problem... I have following parameters set for my subqueries:

```
    with 
      params as (select '2018-06-01'::timestamp p_datum_vlozitve_from, '2019-01-01'::timestamp  p_datum_vlozitve_to, 0:: double precision glavnica_od, 141::double precision glavnica_do, 141::double precision upnikid)
Select --- MAIN QUERY - BELLOW SUBQUERY
    left join (select paketi.id_upnik, sum(specifikacije_postavke.placilo) as pokpravdnistroski
               from specifikacije_postavke, specifikacije1, dolzniki_terjatve, paketi, params
               where specifikacije1.idizracun=specifikacije_postavke.idizracun and dolzniki_terjatve.referenca=specifikacije1.referenca and paketi.id_paket=dolzniki_terjatve.id_paket
               and postavkastroski='4' and obresti=false
               and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica > glavnica_od and dolzniki_terjatve.glavnica < glavnica_do
               and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve >= p_datum_vlozitve_from and dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve < p_datum_vlozitve_to
               and paketi.id_upnik in(upnikid)
               and datumplacila <= date(dolzniki_terjatve.datum_vlozitve) + interval '1 month' 
               group by paketi.id_upnik)
               as tabelapravdnistroski on paketi.id_upnik=tabelapravdnistroski.id_upnik
```

The last one `141::double precision upnikid` goes into part of subquery where the value could be one or more or I have to take all values.

```
    where upniki.upnik_id in (upnikid)
```

So, if I put i param 141::double precision upnikid, the query is working. If I try to put 141,1000::double precision upnikid, it doesn't work any more. How to put more than one value in this param or maybe all values of upniki.id_upnik or none?

Anyone knows the solution?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say. Update the question with the complete query and a description of "doesn't work".

Comment: Query has 1200 rows.

Comment: And that comment helps how? Without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) there is really no way to come up with an answer.

Comment: Check now please

Comment: 1) Why `in(upnikid)`? Should it not be `=upnikid` as there is only one value?  2) You still have not described what is not working?

Comment: I need more than one value. "So, if I put i param 141::double precision upnikid, the query is working. If I try to put 141,1000::double precision upnikid, it doesn't work any more. How to put more than one value in this param or maybe all values of upniki.id_upnik or none?"

Comment: This `141,1000::double precision upnikid` is a shortcut for `141,1000::double precision AS upnikid` where you are giving a value a column alias. There cannot be duplicate column names for the `SELECT` list, so this is not going to work. If you want to do this you will need to put the values in an [ARRAY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html).

Comment: Yeah but if I put it in like this, it only givers results for the last id, 1000. But not for 141

Comment: Like what? Show code.  Best guess is you are looking for [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16)

Comment: I am a rockie. I don't know how to write an array and include it into existing query.

Comment: It is spelled out at the link I posted above.  Quick hint `ARRAY[141.0, 345.5, 78.12]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If param values for conditions in where are delivered in `WITH` statement, then list of values can be delivered as array.

Assuming out table is named `table1`

```
with 
  params as (select array[1,2,3] as list)
Select table1.* from table1, params
where table1.position = any (list)
```

One query example, to play with:

```
with 
  params as (select array[1,2,3] as list)
Select table1.* from (
 values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) as table1(position), params
where table1.position = any (params.list)
```

Comment: It is working. But wht if I want for all ID's, not to excluede any?

Comment: this is condition that check for inclusion

Comment: But sometimes I have to include all... Can I do something which would not affect on queries and subqueries?

Comment: so you may have 2 params...  include_all ... and list, and condition like 

(params.include_all or table1.position = any (params.list))